# Tablesorter - emptyTo not working

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tablesorter

I can't seem to get Mottie's Tablesorter "emptyTo" to work, sorting works but the empty cells sort to the top which I don't want. I'm not trying to do anything special, I am just sorting regular text and there happens to be empty cells which I'd prefer to sort to the bottom.

I tried using the "emptyTo" tablesorter property from: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sort-empty.html but empty spaces still sort to the top.

These are the scripts included:

- jquery.tablesorter.min.js (latest version: v2.18.4, Mottie Rob Garrison FORK)
- jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js

I am using coffeescript:

```
tableOptions =
  emptyTo: 'bottom', //<---- This is the property that should work but isn't :(
  showProcessing: true,
  widthFixed: true,
  widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders'],
  widgetOptions:
    stickyHeaders: '',
    stickyHeaders_offset: 0,
    stickyHeaders_cloneId: '-sticky',
    stickyHeaders_addResizeEvent: true,
    stickyHeaders_includeCaption: true,
    stickyHeaders_zIndex: 2,
    stickyHeaders_attachTo: null,
    stickyHeaders_filteredToTop: true
    stickyHeaders_attachTo: '.scroll'
```

Then...

```
$ ->
  $('.tablesorter').tablesorter(tableOptions)
```

My table structure is the standard tablesorter structure:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm also using bootstrap in this application so I'm not sure if that would affect it in anyway... Let me  know if I'm missing something.

Comment: [From the docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#emptyto), `emptyTo` has a default value of `bottom`, so why set it explicitly. And I hope the comment there is for stackoverflow only, because that's not a valid cs comment style.

Comment: As @maremp said, the `emptyTo` is set to bottom by default. I'm not sure why it's not working for you ([working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4955/)). Maybe a demo showing the problem would make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: @maremp yeah the comment I just put in for stackoverflow, oh yeah you're right CS comment is # haha

Comment: @Mottie yeah, that's what I thought from reading the docs but it wasn't working so I included the option in the table settings just to be sure. It's strange because I'm sure if I create a demo in JSFiddle or something it will work. My actual application will have the rows Generated via a model loop pass through to the view. WHEN there are not enough rows in the model to fill the height of the table (container) then I use Javascript to fill in empty rows with the proper amount of columns based on # of <th> in the table.

Comment: What is called first, table generator or the code above?

Comment: AHhhhh, thanks @maremp...!! Good question, I didn't think that would matter! Turns out it does. I switched the order to generate the rows before initiating Tablesorter and the issue is fixed. If you wanna submit an answer I'll accept. Thanks again I wasted a couple hours on this lol... TBH I was wondering why by default tablesorter would sort empty spaces to the *top*... :P You guys are right though I didn't have to set the option, thanks again.

Comment: Forget to send the comment, thanks for asking me to make an answer, not everyone is so generous to my SO reputation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config is correct, it has some redundant settings (i.e. are default anyway), but better be safe than sorry. The comment on line 2 is not valid CoffeeScript syntax, but that's for purposes of posing on Stack Overflow.

Since you've mentioned the table is generated using javascript (or CoffeeScript, it get's down to the same thing), the order of generating data and using tablesorter is important:

1. load any libraries
2. load script of generator
3. load tablesorter script

If workflow tool is used, such as grunt, gulp etc. and scripts are compiled into a single script it's also important that this order is respected. Both tools listed have a way of specifying order of including scripts.